# mail not sent in php

Tags: php, sendmail, html-email, phpmailer

I try to send mail using php but nothing received. Actual, I want to process the send mail function after a payment gateway process.
Here is my code:

```
$order_id       = $_REQUEST['Order_Id'];
$AuthDesc       = 'Y';  // $_REQUEST['AuthDesc'];
$Checksum       = $_REQUEST['Checksum'];
$price          = $_REQUEST['Amount'];
```

Gateway reply 'Y', 'N' & 'B' . Lets, I hard code it to 'Y' for test.

```
if($AuthDesc == 'Y'){
    $payStatus='SUC';
    $updateSQL="UPDATE `tbl_cc_payment` SET `checksum`='".$Checksum."', `gateway_status`='1', `customer_status`='1' WHERE `order_id`='".$order_id."'";
    $updateRs=mysql_query($updateSQL);

    //Send mail:
    if($updateRs){

        $findmailidsql=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tbl_cc_payment` WHERE `order_id`='".$order_id."'"));
        $cust_mail_id=$findmailidsql['cust_email'];
        $txn_date=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($findmailidsql['txn_date']));

        $to          = $cust_mail_id;
        $subject     = 'Anantonline order confirmation | Transaction ID : '.$order_id;
        $headers     = "From: Pecon Sale Team <sales@pecon.co.in>" . "\r\n";
        $headers    .= "Reply-To: Pecon Sale Team <sales@pecon.co.in>" . "\r\n";
        $headers    .= "CC: transaction@pecon.co.in\r\n";
        $headers    .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers    .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

        $message     = '<html>';
        $message     = '<head><title>Order Confirmation</title></head>';
        $message    .= '<body>';
        $message    .= '<h3>Hello, World!</h3>';
        $message    .= '</table>';
        $message    .= '<tr><td colspan="3" align="left">Dear'.$findmailidsql['billing_cust_name'].',</td></tr>';
        $message    .= '<tr><td colspan="3" align="left">Thank you for signing up with Anant Online.</td></tr>';
        $message    .= '<tr><td colspan="3" align="left">This is an acknowledgement receipt of your subscription for '.ucwords($findmailidsql['suprt_plan']).' with Transaction/Order ID '.$findmailidsql['order_id'].' dated '.$findmailidsql['txn_date'].'</td></tr>';
        $message    .= '<tr><td><strong>The details are shown below:</strong></td></tr>';
        $message    .= '<tr><td>Customer Name</td><td>:</td><td>'.$findmailidsql['billing_cust_name'].'</td></tr>';
        $message    .= '<tr><td>Plan Subscribed</td><td>:</td><td>'.$findmailidsql['suprt_plan'].'</td></tr>';
        $message    .= '<tr><td>Email Address</td><td>:</td><td>'.$findmailidsql['cust_email'].'</td></tr>';
        $message    .= '<tr><td>Customer Id</td><td>:</td><td>'.$findmailidsql['id'].'</td></tr>';
        $message    .= '<tr><td>Amount debited</td><td>:</td><td>'.$findmailidsql['amount'].'</td></tr>';
        $message    .= '<tr><td>Date of Purchase</td><td>:</td><td>'.$txn_date.'</td></tr>';
        $message    .= '<tr><td>Plan Start Date</td><td>:</td><td>'.$txn_date.'</td></tr>';
        $message    .= '<tr><td>Plan Expiry Date</td><td>:</td><td>'.$txn_date.'</td></tr>';
        $message    .= '<tr><td colspan="3" align="left">Please feel free to contact our help desk for further information.</td></tr>';
        $message    .= '<tr><td colspan="3" align="left">We thank you for choosing Anant Online as your solution provider and look forward to serve you through our hassle free , state-of-art remote support.</td></tr>';
        $message    .= '<tr><td colspan="3" align="left">For any further assistance you can log on to http://www.anantonline.com or dial our Helpdesk numbers or e-mail us at support@anantonline.com</td></tr>';
        $message    .= '<tr><td colspan="3" align="left">Please click on the links to read our <a href="http://buy.anantonline.com/terms.php">Terms and Conditions</a> and <a href="http://buy.anantonline.com/refundpolicy.php">Refund Policy</a>.</td></tr>';
        $message    .= '<tr><td colspan="3" align="left">With Regards, <br><strong>Anantonline Sales Team</strong></td></tr>';
        $message    .= '</table>';
        $message    .= '</body>';
        $message    .= '</html>';

        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }


}elseif($AuthDesc == 'N'){
    $payStatus='DEC';
}elseif($AuthDesc == 'B'){
    $payStatus='BAT';
}else{
    $payStatus='UNK';
}

header('location:payment-result.php?txn='.$order_id.'&status='.$payStatus);
```

Please anyone give me a solution to fix this. Thanking you.

Comment: did you set your SMTP?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); `then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: I test it on live not localhost@Kevin

Comment: Have you tried sending to different recipients?
The reason I ask is if your sending mail from a domain and the domain has SPF protection and your IP isn't listed it will be bounced by most email servers.

Comment: yeah I have checked with different recipients, same result @detheridge02

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending SMTP email, you will required to enter below information for smtp

```
$host = "";
$port = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";

$headers = array ('From' => $from,
'To' => $to,
'Subject' => $subject,
'MIME-Version'=>'1.0',
'Content-type'=>'text/html;charset=iso-8859-1');

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
array ('host' => $host,
'port' => $port,
'auth' => true,
'username' => $username,
'password' => $password));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $message);
```